# mysql query with random and desc

Tags: mysql

this is a mysql table

```
num        wt
a          24
e          22
c          11
d          24
b          13
f          12
```

how can i create a mysql query which will display with descending order of weights and give random sorting to num with same weight . thus the select query can have two valid results

```
a    24
d    24
e    22 
b    13
f    12
c    11
```

AND

```
d    24
a    24
e    22 
b    13
f    12
c    11
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY wt DESC, RAND()
```

Comment: +1 But is RAND() really required? Doesn't mysql will return the two valid results if run multiple times?